# Why is my javascript object property disappearing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I am writing a simple AngularJS webapp, and in my Navigation service I have a list of menu items:

```
    class NavigationService {
        constructor($location) {
            this.$location = $location;

            this.menu = [{
                label: 'Overview',
                key: 'overview',
                children: [{
                    label: 'My Balances',
                    key: 'overview_balances',
                    click: () => {
                        this.$location.path('/balances');
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                label: 'Wallets',
                children: [{
                    label: 'Bitcoin',
                    key: 'wallets_bitcoin',
                    click: () => {
                        this.$location.path('/btc/balances');
                    }
                }, {
                    label: 'Ethereum',
                    key: 'wallets_ethereum',
                    click: () => {
                        this.$location.path('/eth/balances');
                    }
                }, {
                    label: 'Add...',
                    key: 'wallets_add',
                    click: () => {
                        this.$location.path('/wallets/add');
                    }
                }]
            }];
        }
        // some other code omitted
    }

    NavigationService.$inject = ['$location'];

    export default NavigationService;
```

However, when I put a breakpoint in the click function of one of the menu items, the `key` property is undefined, even though the label and other values are present:

[image: how it looks]

I am using Webpack to turn ES6 code into boring javascript, but inspecting the resulting bundle.js still shows the `key` property is there upon creation. Also, though the screenshot doesn't show it, the Overview `key` is still present -- it is only the `key`s of the `children` array of objects that are undefined. If they were being removed, why would they show up in the inspector at all?

I know `key` isn't a reserved word in JS, but is it being used differently in Angular? I can certainly pick a different name for the value, but I want to know what is going on. How can I follow that variable in memory and see the point where the key disappears?

Comment: there are quotes for key in the child object for My Balances, Did you try removing that?

Comment: Re: "*is `key` a reserved word?*". It takes a few moments with ECMA-262 to come to the conclusion [*no*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/). Also, reserved words aren't precluded from being used as property names.

Comment: Are you sure you are running under the same scope (same 'menu')? Have you tried to use var self = this; and use self.menu ---> see if this changes anything?

Comment: you can add setter and getter for this key field (using standard js mechanism) and see from where it is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. What was weird was that the tabs weren't reacting the same way, and no matter what I changed the key too, it kept getting set to `undefined`. I realized that my usage of the variable was likely the culprit. Turns out I had `=` instead of `==` in my `ng-class` statement:

```
    <ul class="menu-list">
        <li ng-repeat="child in menu.children">
            <a ng-bind="child.label"
                ng-class="{
                    'is-active': child.id = ctrl.Navigation.current_menu.id
                }"
                ng-click="ctrl.Navigation.select_menu(child)"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Whenever I clicked on the menu item -- or whenever a digest would occur --
 it would set the `child.id` variable to `ctrl.Navigation.current_menu.id` which would be undefined, I guess. Changing it to `==` fixes the problem.